# Coldfusion , Invoke a web service using soap with dynamic soap body xml

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, coldfusion

I need to invoke a soap over HTTP webservice from my coldfusion application. This involves user submitting a form(with lot of fields) and then code should pass all this information to the webservice and get some response. So have been working on a prototype for that.

I have been going thru this forum and have seen lot of code snippets for this but somehow all seem to be passing hardcoded value in the xml section but i need to pass value from a variable. When i try to pass variables etc, the code doesnt treat them as variable but rather as a text value.

My webservice invocation code is :

```
<cfsavecontent variable="soap"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://localhost:8500/Credit Card Soap Web Service"><!---1 this is the cfc location--->

 <!---Optional
    <soapenv:Header>
    <setInit>1</setInit>
    <!--- 2 header param --->
    </soapenv:Header>--->
    <soapenv:Body>
        <authorize soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
        <!---3 cfc method name --->
            <name>#elemName.XmlText#</name>
            <address>1010 Pine St</address>
            <zip>110001</zip>
            <state>MO</state>
            <country>USA</country>
            <cardtype>Visa</cardtype>
            <cardnumber>123123123</cardnumber>
            <expiry>10-12-2020</expiry>
            <amount>50000</amount>
        </authorize>
       </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</cfsavecontent>


<cfhttp url="http://localhost:8500/Credit Card Soap Web Service/Credit Card Soap Web Service authorization.cfc" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-type" value="text/xml">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(soap)#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" name="message" value="#trim(soap)#">
</cfhttp>


<cfdump var="#xmlparse(cfhttp.FileContent)#">
```

---

The webservice at this time is simply returning the values passed to it .Still trying to iron this issue first.

Note the code:

```
>  <name>#elemName.Text#</name> 

>  <address>1010 Pine St</address>
```

Both rows are treated the same way.. as actual value. XmlText  is set as the above value and this doesnt pick the value from the variable.

```
 <cfdump var="#xmlparse(cfhttp.FileContent)#">
```

This prints :

```
  item XmlText  
key XmlText NAME 
XmlAttributes struct 
xmlns:soapenc http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/  
xsi:type soapenc:string  


**value XmlText #elemName.XmlText#** 
XmlAttributes struct 
xmlns:soapenc http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/  
xsi:type soapenc:string
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here. I'm new to CF and still improving my basics.

Also how can i change my encoding style to "Document"

Please let me know if you need further info from me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the variable's value, all you need to do is wrap the ColdFusion variables that are contained within the `<cfsavecontent>` tags with `<cfoutput>` tags.  Like this:

```
 <name><cfoutput>#elemName.XmlText#</cfoutput></name>
```

If you have several ColdFusion variables you can also place the `<cfoutput>` tags around the block of code that contains them, instead of around each individual variable.  Like this:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <cfoutput>
        <authorize soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
            <!---3 cfc method name --->
            <name>#elemName.XmlText#</name>
            <address>#elemAddress.XmlText#</address>
            <zip>#elemZip.XmlText#</zip>
            <state>#elemState.XmlText#</state>
            <country>#elemCountry.XmlText#</country>
            <cardtype>#elemCardType.XmlText#</cardtype>
            <cardnumber>#elemCardNumber.XmlText#</cardnumber>
            <expiry>#elemCardDate.XmlText#</expiry>
            <amount>#elemAmount.XmlText#</amount>
        </authorize>
    </cfoutput>
</soapenv:Body>
```

In your `<cfhttpparam>` tags you should also match the logic for determining the content-length based on the *trimmed* length of your `soap` variable. Since that is what you are passing in the message.  Add the `trim` function to the content-length header.  Like this:

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="content-length" value="#len(trim(soap))#">
```

Comment: Hi this worked like magic. Thanks for your quick response. One more query I have : The actual webservice that we will access has wsdlsoap:binding style is of type "document". 
Do i need to make any changes in my above code to accomodate that?

Comment: I don't think the binding type of document matters for the way you are calling the service.  Are you getting an error or is something not working?

Comment: ok! great. I am yet to start working with the actual webservice. Just working on my invoke skeleton code as of now.
Thanks a ton for ur help.
This may sound bit dumb but wanted to ask anyway : does the above code look OK for invoking a soap-HTTP webservice?

Comment: Also if u could point me to any links where I can get some better idea about CF-Soap stuff.

Comment: Your code above looks good to me so far. Remember to add some error handling and validation on the response you get. As far as links, if you Google 'coldfusion http soap request' you will get LOTS of results to look at. Probably the link that I refer people to most often is the first one on that list from Ben Nadel - [Making SOAP Web Service Requests With ColdFusion And CFHTTP](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1809-Making-SOAP-Web-Service-Requests-With-ColdFusion-And-CFHTTP.htm).

Comment: You are welcome. If you run into any issues just post a new question here on StackOverflow. Good luck!